# The value of a series .

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to find the value of

$$\sum _{t=0}^{n} \binom{n}{t}(q-1)^t$$
where $q$ is a positive integer.

How about the following series:

$$\sum _{t=0}^{n} t\binom{n}{t}(q-1)^t$$

Comment: Yes, use the binomial theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you know the binomial formula:

$$
{(a+b)}^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k} a^k{b}^{n-k}}
$$

So using $a=q-1$ and $b=1$ you get:

$$
{(q-1+1)}^{n}=q^n=\sum_{t=0}^{n}{{n\choose t} {(q-1)}^{t}}
$$

For the second one observe that if we let :

$$
f(q)=\sum_{t=0}^{n}{{n\choose t }{(q-1)}^{t}}=q^n
$$

Then:

$$
\sum_{t=0}^{n}{{n\choose t} t{(q-1)}^{t}}=(q-1)f(q)'=n(q-1){q}^{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 3):

By the Binomial Theorem, you know that $$\displaystyle\sum_{t = 0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{t}(q-1)^t = \left[(q-1)+1\right]^n = q^n.$$

If you differentiate both sides with respect to $q$ to get $$\displaystyle\sum_{t = 0}^{n}t\dbinom{n}{t}(q-1)^{t-1} = nq^{n-1}.$$

To get the sum you wanted, just multiply by $(q-1)$, which gives you $$\displaystyle\sum_{t = 0}^{n}t\dbinom{n}{t}(q-1)^{t} = n(q-1)q^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Given $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{t=0}\binom{n}{t}(q-1)^t\;,$ Now Let $q-1 = x\;, $

Then Sum convert into $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{t=0}\binom{n}{t}x^t = (1+x)^n = (1+q-1)^n = q^n$

Above we have used the formula $\displaystyle \bullet (1+x)^n = \binom{n}{0}x^0+\binom{n}{1}x^1+....\binom{n}{n}x^n$